# sscanf no recoge los datos pedidos

Tags: c, string, txt

he hecho un programa en el que se leen varias lineas de un txt , dentro de la funcion imprimirEmpleado quiero pasar los minutos para ponerlos como h:min para ello divido los minutos entre 60 y me dara un numero (7,5 por ejemplo) , ahora lo que hago es usar sprintf y despues sscanf para coger los datos separados (tendria que multiplicar el 0,5 del ejemplo por 60 y me quedaria 7:30). El problema viene porque no me coge los datos correctamente con el sscanf y no se como hacerlo, aqui les dejo el codigo y el texto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

FILE *abrirFichero (){
FILE *fichero;
int errores=0;
char archivo[40];
do{
    printf("Escribe el nombre del archivo:");
    scanf("%s",archivo);
    fichero = fopen(archivo,"r");
    if(fichero==NULL)  {
      printf("Ha habido un error al abrir el fichero\n");
      errores=errores+1;
    }else{
      printf("Se ha abierto el fichero\n");
    }
}while(fichero==NULL);
    return fichero;
}

int convertirString2Minutos(char marcajes[100]){
    int horas, minutos, n;
    n=sscanf(marcajes,"%d:%d",&horas,&minutos);
    return ((horas*60)+minutos);
}
void procesarDatosTrabajador(char lineas[100], char jornada[100],char nombre[100],char apellido[100],char marcaje[100],char par[100],char impar[100]){
int n,s,TiempoTrabajado=0;
s=sscanf(lineas,"%[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\n]",jornada,nombre,apellido,marcaje);
    if(s!=4){
        printf("Error 1");
    }
    else{
    do{
        n=sscanf(marcaje,"%s %s %[^\n]",par,impar,marcaje);
        TiempoTrabajado=TiempoTrabajado+calculoTiempoTrabajado(par,impar);

    }
    while(n==3);
    }
imprimirEmpleado(nombre,apellido,jornada,TiempoTrabajado);

}

int calculoTiempoTrabajado (char par[100],char impar[100]){
    return (convertirString2Minutos(impar)-convertirString2Minutos(par));
}

void imprimirEmpleado(char nombre[], char apellidos[], char jornada[], int TiempoTrabajado) {

int TiempoJornada, dmin, dhh, dmm, n;
float dh;
char A[200];

    TiempoJornada=convertirString2Minutos(jornada);
    dmin= TiempoJornada-TiempoJornada;
    dh=dmin/60;
    sprintf(A," %f",dh);
    sscanf(A, " %d'%d", &dhh,&dmm);

float sueldo, sueldoE, B;

    if(TiempoTrabajado<=TiempoJornada){
        sueldo=(TiempoTrabajado/60)*8;
        sueldoE=0;
    }else{
        B=(TiempoTrabajado/60)-(TiempoJornada/60);
        sueldo=(TiempoJornada/60)*8;
        sueldoE= B*10;
    }

    printf("Nombre: %-10s\tApellidos: %10s\tDiferencia: %+02d:%02d\tSueldo:%3.2f\tSueldo Extra:%3.2f\n",nombre,apellidos,dhh,dmm,sueldo,sueldoE);
}


void main(){
int n;
char linea1[100],lineas[100],jornada[100],nombre[100],apellido[100],marcaje[100],par[100],impar[100];
FILE *fichero;
fichero=abrirFichero();
fscanf(fichero,"%[^\n]",linea1);
do{
    fscanf(fichero," %[^\n]",lineas);
    procesarDatosTrabajador(lineas,jornada,nombre,apellido,marcaje,par,impar);
}
while(!feof(fichero));


}
```

Contenido del archivo:

```
JORNADA NOMBRE  APELLIDOS   MARCAJES
08:00   Julia   Gonzalez    8:45E 14:50S
06:00   Antonio Lopez Herrera   8:00E 14:45S 16:00E 17:00S
07:36   Maria   Perez Alonso    8:00E 14:45E 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Andrés  Gomez   8:05E 14:45S 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Sara    Martinez Conde  8:00E 14:45S 15:30E 16:45S 18:00E 20:00S
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas escribir los minutos en una cadena para expresar el tiempo de otra manera.

Si recuerdas, la división de enteros tiene 2 resultados. El cociente y el resto (residuo o como lo conozcas).

Bueno, puedes aprovechar esos 2 resultados cuando necesites realizar conversiones.

En una hora hay 60 minutos. Así que para saber las horas solo tienes que dividir por 60. El resto representa lo que sobra. Así que los minutos son el resto de esa división. En C es el [operador %](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Remainder).

```
int minutosTotales = 65;
int horas = minutosTotales / 60;
int minutos = minutosTotales % 60;
```

---

Por cierto, en la línea:

```
dh = dmin/60;
```

`dmin` y `60` son enteros, así que ocurre una división de enteros (pierdes los decimales).

Para que ocurra una división de `float` al menos uno de los dos operandos debe ser de tipo `float`.